# (KnockoutJS) Getting data from a selected table row

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table populated by KnockoutJS. HTML code looks like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col_name">Name</th>
            <th class="col_dob">DOB</th>
            <th class="col_address">Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { id: resource.id}, 
                       css: {'isSelected':$root.selRow() == $data}, 
                       click: $parent.highlightRow.bind($parent), 
                       event : { dblclick: $parent.processRow.bind($parent) }">
            <td class="col_name" data-bind="text: resource.name"></td>
            <td class="col_dob" data-bind="text: resource.birthDate"></td>
            <td class="col_address" data-bind="text: resource.address"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can highlight with a single-click and execute and event on a double-click however when I try to get a data from selected row I'm getting only selected DOM information without data.

KnockoutJS code for that part looks like:

```
this.selectedRow = ko.observable(null);

this.processRow = function(item)
{
        var self = this;
        self.selectedRow(item);

        console.log("Selected data to process: " + JSON.stringify(self.selectedRow(item))); 

}
```

How can I get data from selected row then? Should I do not use `bind` to `$parent` in that case? If so how do I know which row was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item data is being passed into the function correctly, but you're outputting to the console the result of a set operation, which is blank. You've already set the value of selectedRow so there isn't a need to set it again. The console.log line should be reading the value instead of setting it.

```
  this.processRow = function(item)
  {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedRow(item);

    console.log("Selected data to process: " + JSON.stringify(self.selectedRow())); 
  }
```

```js
function viewModel (){
  this.selectedRow = ko.observable(null);
  this.rows = ko.observableArray([
  {resource: new resource()}, {resource: new resource()}, {resource: new resource()}]);

  this.processRow = function(item)
  {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedRow(item);

    console.log("Selected data to process: " + JSON.stringify(self.selectedRow())); 
  }
  
}

function resource(){
  this.name = 'resource name';
  this.birthDate = '1/1/1900';
  this.address = '123 address ln.'
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col_name">Name</th>
            <th class="col_dob">DOB</th>
            <th class="col_address">Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
        <tr data-bind="event : { dblclick: $parent.processRow.bind($parent) }">
            <td class="col_name" data-bind="text: resource.name"></td>
            <td class="col_dob" data-bind="text: resource.birthDate"></td>
            <td class="col_address" data-bind="text: resource.address"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```